# proof about rational roots test theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

show that if the reduced fraction a/b is a root of the equation

$$c_0x^n+c_1x^{n-1}+...+c_n=0$$

where x is areal variable and $c_0,c_1,....,c_n$ are integers $c_0\neq 0$ then $a|c_n$ and $b|c_0$

Approach

$$c_0x^n+c_1x^{n-1}+...+c_n=0$$
$$(c_0(a/b)^n+c_1(a/b)^{n-1}+...+c_n=0$$
$$(c_0(a^n/b^n)+c_1(a^{n-1}/b^{n-1})+...+c_n=0$$
$$b^n(c_0(a^n/b^n)+c_1(a^{n-1}/b^{n-1})+...+c_n=0*b^n$$
$$c_0a^n+c_1(a^{n-1}b^1)+...+c_n*b^n=0$$

if we multiply both sides by b^n then it's easy to see that $c_nb^n=ak$ and $c_0a^n=bd$. We know that the $gcd(a,b)=1$, so $gcd(a,b^n)=1$ and the $gcd(a^n,b)=1$. I proved this by using the bezout's equality. Therefore $a|c_nb^n$ and the $gcd(a,b^n)=1$ so $a|c_n$. That'a a theorem. Similarly $b|c_0$

Comment: The title is wrong here. This should be referring to the rational roots test/theorem.

Comment: $0 = b^nf(\frac{a}b) =  c_0 a^n\! + ab(\cdots) + c_n b^n\ $ so $\ \begin{array}{l}\,a\mid c_nb^n,\, b\mid c_0 a^n\\ \!\Rightarrow  a\mid c_n,\,b\mid c_0\end{array}$ by $(a,b)=1$ and Euclid.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this proof is that it needs to elaborate more on $c_nb^n=ak$ and $c_0a^n=bd$. How did you conclude these two statements? Show your work for concluding these.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like that the indexes for $c$ don't match the powers of $x.$

$p(x) = c_n x^n + \cdots c_1 x + c_0$

Suppose $\frac ab$ is a root of $p(x)$, with $\frac ab$ in lowest terms.

$p(\frac ab) = 0 \\
b^np(\frac ab) = 0\\
c_n a^n + (c_{n-1} b a^{n-1} \cdots c_1 a b^{n-1}) = -c_0 b^n$

$b|c_0 b^n$, and $b|(c_{n-1} b a^{n-1} \cdots c_1 a b^{n-1})$ it must be the case that $b|c_n a^n$

Since $b$ does not divide $a \implies b$ divides $c_n$

Similarly,

$a|c_n a^n + (c_{n-1} b a^{n-1} \cdots c_1 a b^{n-1})\implies a|c_0 b^n\\
a| c_0$